# GPT policy and GPT detectors

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow has issued guidance to moderators across the network to not use GPT detectors to support content moderation.

The TL;DR (as this guidance has not yet been shared publicly) is that GPT detectors are wildly inaccurate and may be more inaccurate when used on text written by non-native English speakers.

You may, and we would love if you would, *continue* to flag low-quality contributions on SFSE - whether or not they appear to be AI-written. Please do not include citations to GPT detectors in your flags. You *can* call out situations where the text includes obvious references or stock phrases used by ChatGPT.

My experience so far as a moderator has been that *virtually all* content that appears to be GPT-written (we all know its prose style by now) is also in violation of some other rule or guideline on our site.

Usually, these answers (they're almost always answers)

- do not directly address the question;
- contain wildly incorrect code or metadata;
- are so vague as to not constitute an answer at all;
- contain contextually inappropriate framing text matching ChatGPT's conversation style.

Please use the site's existsing rules and guidelines to make your flagging decisions, and we will continue to address flags and patterns of user behavior as we always have.

Comment: I certainly get the feeling there are some members who are largely using GPT in answers that (as said here) tend to fail to really answer the question. Here's an [example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/414605/50252), one of two in the last 24 hours like this from the same member.

Comment: I note [this user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/45182/mycoola) seems to specialise in GPT generated answers that they subsequently end up deleting when comments are made against them...

Comment: Yeah, as David asked, keep flagging them. I find peopel are pretty good GPT detectors these days, but when I'm unsure I just copy the question into ChatGPT and see what it generates - it's often very close to the answer posted!